# FOSRestBundle Serializer Error

Tags: php, serialization, symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm getting an error when i work with FOSRestBundle.

> Fatal error: Class 'JMS\Serializer\SerializationContext' not found in
>   /home/a15net/public_html/kavuklar/vendor/friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle/FOS/RestBundle/View/ViewHandler.php
>   on line 209

It was working before composer.phar update.

Do you any have idea about this why i'm getting this error?

Comment: @mkjasinski i did not touch anything. So i'm not sure that.

Comment: `JMSSerializerBundle` is registered in `AppKernel.php`?

Comment: @mkjasinski yes new JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle($this), but i'v searched for this file and find nothing. I think the file is updated as just Serializer.php

Comment: cache cleared after `composer.phar update`?

Comment: yes i did it myself to be sure.

Comment: hmmm... no, file exists in source [SerializerContext.php](https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/blob/master/src/JMS/Serializer/SerializationContext.php).

Comment: I don't know how but composer had failed i think. Because there are no such a file as SerializerContext.php . I will remove vendor directory and reinstall it again.

Comment: exactly, it's probably the only way

Comment: no, didn't work... composer creating all files but the SerializerContext.php

Comment: hmmm... remove package `JMSSerializerBundle` from `composer.lock`, remove vendor dir and install again.

Comment: Still not working. I don't understand why it's not downloading these files...

Comment: get file from github and copy to vendor directory, than report a problem.

Comment: It's not about just that file. That file using other files to do things. Requirement files are missing too... Sadly

Comment: experiment: get source from github and copy to vendor directory, works?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem.

I solved it reading [the FOSRestBundle upgrade file](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/UPGRADING.md), and then updating my **composer.json**. You should try to put in require section this next lines:

```
"friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "0.11.*",
"jms/serializer-bundle": "0.12.x-dev"
```

and then

`composer.phar update`

It works for me.

Try and comment.

Comment: Thank you brother. Really saved my day! But now, i have another problem. Now serializer can't access a private property.

`Cannot access private property ATL\CatalogBundle\Entity\Taxonomy::$id in`

Do you know how can i handle this?

Comment: I need more information. I tried to return some entity data in json format with serializer and it works perfectly for me. Maybe your entity have something extrange. Do you try to search a bit? Perhaps you need open a new question